# Importing gradle project into Spring Tool Suite leads to dependency error

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, gradle

I've installed the latest Spring Tool Suite on Windows and have tried installing the Gradle plugin a variety of ways - by doing it first and starting over and installing the Groovy plugin first because I read that somewhere. Either way, when I try to import a Grails project into my workspace and press the Build Model button, I receive the following error:

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not find group:bmuschko, module:gradle-tomcat-plugin, version:0.9.3.
>   Required by:
>   :bookstore:unspecified
>   Could not find group:bmuschko, module:gradle-cargo-plugin, version:0.5.4.
>   Required by:
>   :bookstore:unspecified

Do you have any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Please don't double-post on Stackoverflow and the Gradle forum. You will find the answer in [your question on the Gradle forum](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/dependency_problem-30i8o).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to specify a directory path or paths by setting your CLASSPATH environmental variable or you can use the -classpath option with java and javac to specify the path.